# Azure - az aks cli azure ad error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-container-service, azure-aks

I have two different Azure Ad tenants

First one is `foo`

Second one is `bar`

and one subscription

Name is `baz`

Account administrator seems as  `foo` at Management & Billing Overview service section.

When I change directory into bar from portal i can see `baz` at  `Other subscriptions` from `Cost Management & Billing.`

When I execute command below at `bar`'s shell, I can see that owner of the subscription is `foo`.

```
azure account show
```

When I execute command below I'm having error "directory permission is needed for the current user to register the application"

```
az aks create --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster --node-count 1 --generate-ssh-keys
```

So I wanna take everything to `foo` create my Azure Kubernetes Service. What should I have to do.  Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please check your account's directory role in second Azure AD?

Comment: Foo is global administrator, bar is user.

Comment: Have you check app registrations settings?

Comment: Yes. At foo it's checked to yes at bar most of the sections seems passive.

Comment: It means you have not permissions, please contact that AAD administrator to change that settings.

Comment: What if I to move subscription from bar to foo. Would it solve my problem? Because my administrator is nearly sure for he gave the right permissions.

Comment: No, move is not a good idea. Could you please check users in second AAD and find the global admin, change Azure AD directory role.

Comment: Could you please ask your admin to change `App registrations` settings or set your directory role as global admin?

Comment: I cannot see any user in bar directory also cannot add a new user only new guest user button seems active.

Comment: and my administration says that he gave me the full access on this account.

Comment: Is your account in that directory user type is a GUEST?

Answer (score 1):

According to your error message, it seems your account doesn't have permissions in your second AAD tenant to create new application registrations.

Please check your account's directory role in second Azure AD(Global admin).

Also, if you can't set your account as Global admin, please check your AAD `user settings` -> `App registrations`, set to **Yes** , if set to Yes, non-admin users can register AD apps.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Update:

You can check AD role here(also your admin can change this settings):

[image]

Comment: You can check your AD role here, I have update my answer, please check it.

Comment: I don't have the section `Directory Role` at AAD.Here is how my portal looks like from bar directory. https://ibb.co/ivQSPc

Comment: uhh my bad. Now I can see only one user at foo which is the same as the ss you shared with me.But at bar there is no user exists.Here is ss of bar's user section from AAD https://ibb.co/fxOZnx

Comment: It seems you are the guest of that directory, could you please contact that directory admin to grant you permission?

Comment: Could you use that telnet to create aks now?

Comment: Still not... Seems no hope for my situation. I dunno what to try more...

Comment: You are a guest of that directory, maybe you should ask that admin add you to his subscription, in this way you will able to create SP and aks.